# highlight not working on figure captions

Tags: highlighting

I am using highlight package where I use \hl command to highlight certain sentences. But when It comes to a figure caption, it gives wierd errors and stops working. Any suggestions on this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\centering
\textbf{Simulation A2}

\begin{figure}[h]

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{trail_fig}

\caption{\label{trail}\hl{(a) Variation of nonboned interactions with time between Asp$^1$ of chain D and Gly$^{38}$ of chain G \& Ala$^{42}$ of chain F,H.(figure {\ref{fig2}g}, {\ref{fig2}i} of the main article)}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\caption{\hl{Trail Caption}}`. This will only highlight the "Trail Caption", but not the "Figure 1".

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Works perfect. Thank you. Anyway to highlight `Figure 1`